# Hero Card Image Rendering Broken for My CDN-Hosted Images

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm working on a bot that sends hero cards with images. In the past these have worked fine, but suddenly the images have stopped rendering, if I host them on my own CDN. The images can be accessed fine via the browser (e.g. https://apps.chitchattr.com/images/CEO.jpg), but when rendered via the bot they show an error (e.g. https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2fapps.chitchattr.com%2fimages%2fCEO.jpg). If I test an image from another random test site (which the url indicates is also coming from a CDN, interestintly), then the render is fine, e.g. https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2flittlecoffeefox.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2018%2f06%2fPhoto-2-1024x683.jpg (which actually redirects to https://urlp.sfbassets.com/urlpcdn/weu1/contentapi1/c1d443bd-1b14-447e-8087-bc8f689251c4).

As I said, these images were working fine until a short time ago. Is there something I need to do to host the images differently? To encode the path somehow (like maybe to indicate to Teams that it's already on a CDN so doesn't need to use whatever Teams seems to be trying to do)? Something else?

Comment: Let me test it at my end, And could you please confirm which adaptive card version you are using?

Comment: What happens if you test the above payload with the above image locations in the [Adaptive card playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net)? Does it work?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I forgot that for this piece of the bot, it's sending a Hero card, not an Adaptive card. Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out - my server was set up to only accept TLS 1.3 requests - I had to enable 1.2 as well, and then Teams was able to request, and show, these images again. Hope this is useful to someone else.